# Reading error output hangs for command invoked on CMD process

Tags: c#, process, cmd, stderr, system.diagnostics

I have c# console app for ffmpeg command invocation. Here is it

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo cmd = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");

        cmd.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.RedirectStandardError = true;
        cmd.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process console = Process.Start(cmd);

        console.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd C:\Users\vishnu.aravind");                     
        console.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"ffmpeg -i sunp.avi -i Alarm03.wav  -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental output.avi");     

        string errors = console.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine("Video file is created.");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

if I remove the line of code

```
string errors = console.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

this program will work fine. Else it hangs. I need the error information if any, what to do, please help.

Answer (score 2):

#### Cause of a problem

Your program hangs because

- *cmd* is an interactive command line application and thus *continually* produces output for *std. out* and *std. error* stream
- `Process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()` reads the output of *std. error* stream of a process till it reaches end of stream

as *cmd* is an interactive command line application - it will not end it's *std. error* stream until process of *cmd* terminates - and that's why `Process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()` hangs when it is invoked on running *cmd* process.

#### Solution for a problem

To get output for each command you execute there are at least two following options:

1. Start each command with separate `Process` instance - and read output with standard methods of `StreamReader` class (`ReadToEnd()` and `Read()` methods).
2. Use single `Process` instance for *cmd* application - to read and write to it interactively:

   - Start process as in following example:

     ```
     Process interactiveProcess = new Process();
     string processOutput = "";

     interactiveProcess.StartInfo.FileName = this.processPath;
     interactiveProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = commandLineParameters;
     interactiveProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     interactiveProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
     interactiveProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
     interactiveProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
     interactiveProcess.Start();

     interactiveProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

     interactiveProcess.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((process, outputEventArgs) => processOutput += outputEventArgs.Data);

     interactiveProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
     ```
   - Write commands to *cmd* with following code

     ```
     interactiveProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
     ```
   - To read response you will need to use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()` method and wait till `processOutput` variable is populated with output during execution of started commands.

Comment: Hi i edited my code as per your advice. It performs better. But all the ffmpeg error messages are not getting. I Installed my ffmpeg.exe in C:\users\vishnu.aravind. Suppose if i run ffmpeg from C:\ only it shows the error message as 'FFmpeg is not recognized as the command'. This error message is a good error message. But if i edit Alarm03.wav in my code posted to Alarm04.wav (which is unavailable in the folder) it has to show some error messages. But unfortunately it doesn't show.

Comment: @user1665130 I see 2 potential problems that might prevent you from getting error messages. **First:** your *ffmpeg* command might be not started correctly with your code - to start it you must not place it's executable in root of `C:` drive, just specify full path to command's file when you invoke it in code. **Second:** text of errors might be routed through *standard output stream* instead of *error output stream* by *ffmpeg* command.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait for exit before reading errors:

```
cmd.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: cmd.WaitForExit is Unavailable. I tried  console.WaitForExit(); No use.