# foreach loop background worker issue

Tags: c#, .net

I have developed a wpf program for video audio merging using ffmpeg tool. I am using background worker class for this purpose. I will include my code here.

```
    public VideoAudioMergeUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
    }

    void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       string progress= e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Process interactiveProcess = new Process();
        string processOutput = "";
        interactiveProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"E:\ffmpeg.exe";
        interactiveProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        interactiveProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        interactiveProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        interactiveProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        ObservableCollection<VideoAudioCombined> videosAudios = (ObservableCollection<VideoAudioCombined>)e.Argument;
        foreach (VideoAudioCombined va in videosAudios)
        {

                string absoluteVideoPath = aviVideoPath + va.Video;
                string absoluteAudioPath = wavAudioPath + va.Audio;
                string relativeVideoPathSplit = va.Video.Substring(0, va.Video.Length - 4);
                string relativeAudioPathSplit = va.Audio.Substring(0, va.Audio.Length - 4);
                string outputavi = relativeVideoPathSplit + "_" + relativeAudioPathSplit + ".avi";
                string SelectedFileNameToSave = selectedFolder + outputavi;

                interactiveProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i " + absoluteVideoPath + "  -i  " + absoluteAudioPath + "   -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental " + SelectedFileNameToSave + " ";
                interactiveProcess.Start();
                interactiveProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                interactiveProcess.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((process, outputEventArgs) => processOutput += outputEventArgs.Data);
                interactiveProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
                bw.ReportProgress(100);

        }
    }



private void ButtonMerge_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

        {
            System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
            folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
            folderDlg.Description = Properties.Resources.MSG_Select_Folder_Merge_Audio_Video;

            // Show the FolderBrowserDialog.
            System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = folderDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                selectedFolder = folderDlg.SelectedPath+"\\";

            }
            bw.RunWorkerAsync(VideoAudioCollection);         
        }
```

The first iteration of the loop doesn't make any issues. The second iteration brings the following issue - "An async read operation has already been started on the stream." Please help.

Comment: Where is the part of the code, that starts the background-worker?

Comment: I included the code for calling the background worker.

Comment: The cause of your error is the line 'interactiveProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();'. You don't have to invoke that method using a single process in the foreach loop. In the first iteration you started the async read operation and it continues, but in the next iteration this operation was already started. You have to review the logic to start the process.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start the background-worker, make sure `IsBusy` is false:

```
if (!bw.IsBusy) 
{
    bw.RunWorkerAsync(VideoAudioCollection);
}
```

If IsBusy is true that means the backgroundworker is still working and hasn't completed it's function yet. In this case it will throw an exception. If this happens you could display a message box saying 
"There is still a merging operation in progress, please wait until that one has finished".

Also you could try to cancel the current running operation calling

```
bw.CancelAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your error is the line: `interactiveProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();`

You don't have to invoke that method using a single process in the foreach loop.

In the first iteration you started the async read operation and it continues. Indeed, in the next iteration this operation was already started.
According to the documentation:

> When asynchronous read operations start, the event handler is called
>   each time the associated Process writes a line of text to its
>   StandardError stream.

You have to review the logic to start the process. I think you should start a different process for each iteration of the loop, because, for each iteration you're using the same process with different parameters, but the same `StandardError` stream.

Further info about the method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginerrorreadline%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi I need that logic. In each iteration there is a chance of getting errors since the filenames are diffrenet in each iteration. So i need to save the errors in each iteration if any. Please help

Comment: @user1665130 As advice, accept the answers of other users like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20566390/702048). The SO users will help you more gladly if you do that. I just said where the error is and how you can solve the problem: 'you should start a different process for each iteration of the loop'.